# Jquery Como somar valores de input em tempo real?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Sou iniciante e tenho um sistema em que o usuário pode adicionar vários inputs dinamicamente, preciso que ao digitar os valores (em decimais)  a soma total seja exibida em uma div. Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei mto agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função keyup() do jQuery, para realizar uma ação sempre que alguma número for inserido em um input.

Documentação do keyup: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/.

```js
$(".NomeClasseInputs").keyup(function(){
    var soma = 0;
    $(this).each(function() {
        soma += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
})
```

O keyup() vai ser executado sempre que houver alguma ação dentro de algum input, e a função de dentro está passando por cada input e realizando a soma dos valores.

Lembrando que para isso funcionar todos os inputs devem possuir a mesma classe. A soma ficará armazenada na variável soma, que você pode inserir em qualquer div com o .html():

```js
$('.idDiv').html(soma);
```